# Marriage in Japan without a visa

Tags: marriage, japan

I'm Irish and I will be traveling to Japan on the visa exemption. I'm planning to get married to a Japanese girl while I'm there. Is this allowed on the visa exemption program? I believe some countries don't allow you get married without getting some kind of fiancée visa.

Would it then be OK to stay in Japan after getting married without having to leave first?

Comment: Are you planning to stay in Japan indefinitely?  If so you should ask at [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: @phoog I want to visit Japan first before we decide where to live. She's been to Ireland a few times already. This will be my first time in Japan.

Comment: Well _if_ you can marry in Japan as a visitor, you certainly ought to be able to stay for the remainder of the allowed duration of the visit.  It looks like this is [six months for Irish citizens provided you apply for an extension of the initial 90 days](https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html#notice08).  How much longer than 6 months would you want to stay?

Comment: @phoog My understanding is that when we get married, I can change my status in Japan to stay for as long as we are married, without me having to leave the country and come back on a spouse visa. Just want to make sure my understanding is correct.

Comment: What official sources have you checked and/or [contacted](https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/index.html) so far? [This guidance](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1088368/20220507_Marriage_in_Japan__guidance_note_.pdf) relates to UK citizens, there’s no reference to a visa as far as I can see, an FAQ around proof of address for non-Japanese residents might be an indication that marrying as a visitor is allowed

Comment: Note: this is a good question for the embassy. And you need to contact it in any case, to have the documents to be able to marry. (e.g. proof you are not already married, etc.).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi this is a (relatively) generic question, we should be able to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got married in Japan in 2008 on a tourist visa. As far as I know, nothing about the procedure has changed in the meantime. The Japanese side of things was pretty easy; I don't remember all the details, but it was just a bit of paperwork at the local municipal office. Some light googling says you just need:

- the application for registration of marriage
- birth certificates
- passport
- affidavit of competency to marry

Which sounds about right. As a German citizen, that last one was actually the hardest to obtain from the German embassy and required obtaining and translating a bunch of Japanese documents to German and the resulting *Ehefähigkeitsbescheinigung* back to Japanese, which took a month or two to get done.

Once we had all that sorted out, we just went to the municipal office and the whole thing was done in half an hour or so. I then went and applied for a spouse visa, which I got some months later. I was allowed to remain in Japan while the visa was still being processed and the tourist visa had already run out.

---

Details may vary based on the exact municipality where you're getting married (though it should be pretty unified across the country), so check the details there. As a random sample, here's the Shinjuku ward's page: https://www.city.shinjuku.lg.jp/todokede/koseki02_000006.html

They just list the form, birth certificates/family registry and some form of id as required items. They do note this though:

> 夫または妻、夫と妻が外国籍の方の場合、婚姻届に必要な書類等が国ごとに異なりますので、あらかじめご相談ください

> If either or both spouses are foreign nationals, additional documents may be necessary and vary by country. Please contact us in advance.